# Полиморфизм. Музыкальные инструменты

Tags: c++

Я прошу прощения, за то что дублирую вопрос. Но я действительно долго не могу решить задачу и мне необходима ваша помощь на данном шаге. Я убрал динамическую память, т.к. с ней тяжело работать и решил вызывать функции всего один раз.
В общем задача.

Мне нужно создать класс Оркестр, у которого будет модифицирован вывод данных, то есть он будет выводить все инструменты, но с условием, что первые будут духовые. 
Дальше мне нужно создать массив оркестр и вызвать эту самую функцию. Я понимаю, я не использую весь язык на полную, т.к. нас учат понимаю основ, а остальные встроенные функции языка будут в дальнейшем, поэтому мне нужно решить задачу и желательно не менять сам стиль, который у меня сейчас. В общем-то, заранее спасибо за помощь.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Класс музыкальные инструменты
class instrument
{
protected:
    string name, firm;
    int cost;
public:     
    instrument(): name("NULL"), firm("NULL"), cost(0)
    {}

    virtual ~instrument() = default;

    void GetInst()
    {
        cout << "\nВведите название инструмента: "; cin >> name;
        cout << "Введите производителя: "; cin >> firm;
        cout << "Введите цену: "; cin >> cost;
    }
    void PutInst()
    {
        cout << "\nИнструмент: " << name;
        cout << "\nПроизводитель: " << firm;
        cout << "\nЦена: " << cost;     
    }
    virtual void GetData() = 0; 
    virtual void PutData() = 0;
};

//Духовые инструменты
class WindInst: public instrument
{
protected:
    int year, LC; //LC - длина канала
    string material, color, type;
public:
    WindInst(): material("Metal"), color("White"), year(2018), LC(0), type("W")
    {}

    void GetData()
    {
        cout << "\nДуховой" << endl;
        instrument::GetInst();
        cout << "Введите год: "; cin >> year;  
        cout << "Введите длину канала духового инструмента: "; cin >> LC;
        cout << "Введите материал: "; cin >> material;
        cout << "Введите цвет: "; cin >> color;
    }
    void PutData()
    {
        cout << "\nДуховой" << endl;
        cout << "\nТип инструмента: " << type;
        instrument::PutInst();
        cout << "\nГод: " << year; 
        cout << "\nДлина духового канала: " << LC;
        cout << "\nМатериал: " << material;
        cout << "\nЦвет: " << color << endl;
    }               
};

//Фортепиано
class PianoInst: public instrument
{
protected:
    int year;
    int NON, key;
    string material, type;
public:
    PianoInst(): key(85), NON(7), material("Tree"), year(2018), type("P")
    {}

    void GetData()
    {
        cout << "\nКлавишный" << endl;
        instrument::GetInst();
        cout << "Введите год: "; cin >> year;  
        cout << "Введите материал: "; cin >> material;
    }
    void PutData()
    {
        cout << "\nКлавишный" << endl;
        cout << "\nТип инструмента: " << type;
        instrument::PutInst();
        cout << "\nГод: " << year; 
        cout << "\nКоличество нот: " << NON;
        cout << "\nКоличество клавиш: " << key;
        cout << "\nМатериал: " << material << endl;
    }               
};

//Струнные инструменты
class StringInst: public instrument
{
protected:
    int year, NOS; //Количество струн (NOS)
    string material, color, type;
public:
    StringInst(): material("Steel"), color("Red"), year(2018), NOS(0), type("ST")
    {}

    void GetData()
    {
        cout << "\nСтрунный" << endl;
        instrument::GetInst();
        cout << "Введите год: "; cin >> year;  
        cout << "Введите количество струн: "; cin >> NOS;
        cout << "Введите материал: "; cin >> material;
        cout << "Введите цвет: "; cin >> color;
    }
    void PutData()
    {   
        cout << "\nСтрунный" << endl;
        cout << "\nТип инструмента: " << type;
        instrument::PutInst();
        cout << "\nГод: " << year; 
        cout << "\nКоличество струн: " << NOS;
        cout << "\nМатериал: " << material;
        cout << "\nЦвет: " << color << endl;    
    }
};

class Orchestra: public instrument
{
private:
    StringInst S;
    PianoInst P;
    WindInst W;
public:

    void PutAll()
    {   
        cout << "Духовой" << endl;
        W.PutData();
        cout << "Клавишный" << endl;
        S.PutData();
        cout << "Струнный" << endl;
        P.PutData();    
    }   
};
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    system ("chcp 1251 && cls");
    srand(time(NULL));
    int n = 0, s = -1, h=2, L=0;
    bool k = true;
    char choice;
    instrument *INST; 
    Orchestra *Or[2];
    WindInst WI;
    StringInst SI;
    PianoInst PI;

    while(true){
    cout << "     Выберите дальнейшее действие: " << endl;
    cout << "1) Ввод инструментов" << endl;
    cout << "2) Вывод всех инструментов" << endl;
    cout << "3) Оркестр" << endl;
    cout << "0) Выход" << endl << endl;
    cout << "S=";
    cin >> s;
    system("cls");
    switch(s) {
        case 1: {
            INST = &PI;
            INST -> GetData();
            INST = &WI;
            INST -> GetData();
            INST = &SI;
            INST -> GetData();
            system("cls");  
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            INST = &PI;
            INST -> PutData();
            INST = &WI;
            INST -> PutData();
            INST = &SI;
            INST -> PutData();
            system("pause");
            system("cls");

            break;
        }
        case 3: {
        for (int m = 0; m < 2; n++)
        Or[m] -> PutAll();
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
        break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Поясните, что именно не получается у Вас сделать, а также уточните задание, как должна вести себя программа при случае 2 и в случае 3. А также, что из себя должен представлять класс Оркестр (в вашем примере этот класс просто включает в себя 3 инструмента).

Comment: Класс оркестр должен просто выводить инструменты, но обязательным условием является, чтобы первые выводились духовые инструменты. В case 2 я просто вывожу все инструменты, которые были записаны. В case 3 мне нужно вызвать метод класса оркестр, который выводит их в нужном порядке. Не получается правильно написать класс оркестр, чтобы он выводил их в нужном порядке(Я в принципе не понимаю, что я там должен написать) и так же в case 3 вывести их с помощью массива типа оркестра, который будет хранить в себе эти самые инструменты.

Comment: В вашем случае case 2 выводит только 3 последних введенных инструмента, если я правильно понял, то вместо этого должны быть выведены все инструменты, которые вводились до этого, при чем не отсортированные? Я не совсем понимаю смысл класса оркестр, когда он содержит всего 3 инструмента, может по условию этот класс должен является своего рода контейнером для объектов типа инструмент?

Comment: Честно вам скажу, я тоже не понимаю, зачем преподаватель сказал мне его сделать. Вот надо и всё. Раньше, у меня было много инструментов, я работал с динамической памятью, но решил убрать её, так как не смог до конца разобраться в ней. Решил сделать всего для трех инструментов. Оркестр мне нужен для модифицированного вывода. Он просто должен вывести всё, как в case 2, но с условием, что 1 инструмент будет духовым. Я могу скинуть код программы с динамической памятью, но разве с ней не сложней работать, чем с этим?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По минимуму подправил Вашу программу

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

//Класс музыкальные инструменты
class instrument
{
protected:
    string name, firm;
    int cost;
public:
    instrument() : name("NULL"), firm("NULL"), cost(0)
    {}

    virtual ~instrument() = default;

    void GetInst()
    {
        cout << "\nВведите название инструмента: "; cin >> name;
        cout << "Введите производителя: "; cin >> firm;
        cout << "Введите цену: "; cin >> cost;
    }
    void PutInst()
    {
        cout << "\nИнструмент: " << name;
        cout << "\nПроизводитель: " << firm;
        cout << "\nЦена: " << cost;
    }
    virtual void GetData() = 0;
    virtual void PutData() = 0;
};

//Духовые инструменты
class WindInst : public instrument
{
protected:
    int year, LC; //LC - длина канала
    string material, color, type;
public:
    WindInst() : material("Metal"), color("White"), year(2018), LC(0), type("W")
    {}

    void GetData()
    {
        cout << "\nДуховой" << endl;
        instrument::GetInst();
        cout << "Введите год: "; cin >> year;
        cout << "Введите длину канала духового инструмента: "; cin >> LC;
        cout << "Введите материал: "; cin >> material;
        cout << "Введите цвет: "; cin >> color;
    }
    void PutData()
    {
        cout << "\nДуховой" << endl;
        cout << "\nТип инструмента: " << type;
        instrument::PutInst();
        cout << "\nГод: " << year;
        cout << "\nДлина духового канала: " << LC;
        cout << "\nМатериал: " << material;
        cout << "\nЦвет: " << color << endl;
    }
};

//Фортепиано
class PianoInst : public instrument
{
protected:
    int year;
    int NON, key;
    string material, type;
public:
    PianoInst() : key(85), NON(7), material("Tree"), year(2018), type("P")
    {}

    void GetData()
    {
        cout << "\nКлавишный" << endl;
        instrument::GetInst();
        cout << "Введите год: "; cin >> year;
        cout << "Введите материал: "; cin >> material;
    }
    void PutData()
    {
        cout << "\nКлавишный" << endl;
        cout << "\nТип инструмента: " << type;
        instrument::PutInst();
        cout << "\nГод: " << year;
        cout << "\nКоличество нот: " << NON;
        cout << "\nКоличество клавиш: " << key;
        cout << "\nМатериал: " << material << endl;
    }
};

//Струнные инструменты
class StringInst : public instrument
{
protected:
    int year, NOS; //Количество струн (NOS)
    string material, color, type;
public:
    StringInst() : material("Steel"), color("Red"), year(2018), NOS(0), type("ST")
    {}

    void GetData()
    {
        cout << "\nСтрунный" << endl;
        instrument::GetInst();
        cout << "Введите год: "; cin >> year;
        cout << "Введите количество струн: "; cin >> NOS;
        cout << "Введите материал: "; cin >> material;
        cout << "Введите цвет: "; cin >> color;
    }
    void PutData()
    {
        cout << "\nСтрунный" << endl;
        cout << "\nТип инструмента: " << type;
        instrument::PutInst();
        cout << "\nГод: " << year;
        cout << "\nКоличество струн: " << NOS;
        cout << "\nМатериал: " << material;
        cout << "\nЦвет: " << color << endl;
    }
};

class Orchestra
{
private:
    StringInst S;
    PianoInst P;
    WindInst W;
public:

    static void PutAll(vector<Orchestra>::iterator begin, vector<Orchestra>::iterator end, bool isSort = false) noexcept
    {
        if (isSort) {
            for (auto it = begin; it < end; it++) 
                it->W.PutData();
            for (auto it = begin; it < end; it++) 
                it->S.PutData();
            for (auto it = begin; it < end; it++) 
                it->P.PutData();
        }
        else {
            for (auto it = begin; it < end; it++) {
                it->W.PutData();
                it->S.PutData();
                it->P.PutData();
            }
        }
    }
    Orchestra(StringInst _s, PianoInst _p, WindInst _w) : S(_s), P(_p), W(_w) {}
    Orchestra() {}
};
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    system("chcp 1251 && cls");
    srand(time(NULL));
    int n = 0, s = -1, h = 2, L = 0;
    bool k = true;
    char choice;
    instrument *INST;
    vector<Orchestra> or;       // контейнер с объектами типа Оркестр
    WindInst WI;
    StringInst SI;
    PianoInst PI;

    while (true) {
        cout << "     Выберите дальнейшее действие: " << endl;
        cout << "1) Ввод инструментов" << endl;
        cout << "2) Вывод всех инструментов" << endl;
        cout << "3) Оркестр" << endl;
        cout << "0) Выход" << endl << endl;
        cout << "S=";
        cin >> s;
        system("cls");
        switch (s) {
        case 1: {
            INST = &PI;
            INST->GetData();
            INST = &WI;
            INST->GetData();
            INST = &SI;
            INST->GetData();
            or.push_back(Orchestra(SI, PI, WI));            // Добавляем инструменты в наш контейнер
            system("cls");
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            Orchestra::PutAll(or.begin(), or.end());
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            Orchestra::PutAll(or.begin(), or.end(), true);
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            break;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Эх, опять вектора, итераторы... Ладно. Все равно, большое спасибо вам за помощь.